# How to attach a mdf file in C# with SQL Express 2012 installed but keep as SQL Express 2005?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows application that use a SQL Server 2005 Express `.mdf` file and I have many clients already with that application and the SQL Server 2005 Express versions on they computers.

Now I'm testing in my development machine but with SQL Server 2012 Express and my problem is that when my application wants to attach the `.mdf` file it changes its version and my Windows application won't work after that.

It is possible to attach a `.mdf` file without increasing that version?

Comment: No, you cannot do this. Once you attach your `.mdf` file to a 2012 version, it's upgraded automatically (and you cannot prevent that from happening), and once that's done, it's no longer compatible with the 2005 versions out there (cannot be attach to a 2005 instance anymore)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the compatibility level of your DB.

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbNmae> SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90 -- for SQL SERVER 2005 compatibility
```

Comment: Yes, but the compatibility level doesn't help here - once the `.mdf` is converted (internally) to a 2012 version, regardless of which compatibility level you have, you cannot re-attach it back to a 2005 instance.